# Facebook SDK FBRequest requestForMe Incompatible pointer types

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am running into issues trying upgrade my Facebook SDK to the latest production release (FacebookSDK-3.0.8.pkg - Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS (update 1) [August 21, 2012]).

I am following along with tutorial on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#coding).

I have ran into several issues trying to get the code to work, it's not as easy as it proclaims to be in the tutorial. I can get my session open, but can not get the request to work.

```
- (IBAction)facebookTapped:(id)sender {
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error opening session: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    if(session.isOpen) {
        NSLog(@"session is open");

        FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me"];
        [me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my,
                                         NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"My name: %@", my.first_name);
        }];
    }

    }];
    }
```

My console displays that the session is open if I remove the call to FBRequest requestforGraphpath. If I leave it in, I receive the error "Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void(^)(struct FBRequestConection *, struct NSDictionary*, struct NSError*)', expected 'FBRequestHandler'

Now what has me stumped is that this is the exact code shown in the tutorial, excpet that I changed out [FBRequest requestForMe] trying different approaches. None worked.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Since the 48-hour time limit is past, can you post the edit as an answer now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing their original block in the tutorial of:

```
if (session.isOpen) {
FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[me startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, 
                                  NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my,
                                  NSError *error) {
    self.label.text = my.first_name;
}];
}
```

to

```
if(session.isOpen) {   
        FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
        [me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         id result,
                                         NSError *error) {
            NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *) result;
           NSLog(@"My dictionary: %@", my.first_name);
        }];
    }
```